# Latexmk ignore a file

Tags: latexmk

I have a directory of `.tex` files that I want to build using `latexmk` by running `latexmk` in that directory. However, there is one `.tex` file that is included by all other files, which is not a valid document in itself, and should therefore not be compiled.

Removing the `.tex` extension from the specific file is not an option, because LuaLaTeX will not find it otherwise.

Comment: From [the latexmk documentation](http://users.phys.psu.edu/~collins/software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-442.txt), you can use the `@default_files` variable in a `.latexmkrc` to set the list of files that will be built when no file is specified. Alternatively, on a Unix-like system, you could use a for loop and run latexmk on a specified set of files: `for n in [a-m]*.tex [o-z]*.tex; do latexmk $n; done` (which would exclude any tex file starting with `n`).

Comment: Two other possibilities: 1. Change the extension of the file from `.tex` to something else, e.g., `.inc`.  Then LuaLaTeX will find it.  2.  Use the (not-yet-documented) configuration array variable `@default_excluded_files`, as in `@default_excluded_files = ('common.tex');` in a `.latexmkrc` file.

Comment: Using a different extension is a fine workaround, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Two other possibilities:
>
> 1. Change the extension of the file from `.tex` to something else, e.g., `.inc`. Then LuaLaTeX will find it.
> 2. Use the (not-yet-documented) configuration array variable `@default_excluded_files` in a `.latexmkrc` file, as in:
>
> ```perl
> @default_excluded_files = ('common.tex');
> ```

[- John Collins | 2015 Feb](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/229210/latexmk-ignore-a-file#comment541244_229210)

Comment: how does it "not provide an answer to the question"? it directly addresses the question - "not compile a .tex file via latexmk" as also acknowledged by the questioner in the comment replies: "Using a different extension is a fine workaround, thanks!". and where did it "require clarification from asker" ?